# Setting up a proxy on Nginx, very basic

Tags: proxy, nginx

Hi I am used to working with Apache and Mod proxy where I my server configuration looks a bit like this and I redirect all incoming requests from

```
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/trunk/public



  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / http://mentoredge.com



    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName o.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

Here I route all my incoming request on o.example.com to port 8000 of localhost.

I have migrated to Nginx now im trying to setup this proxy for the same o.example.com. Could somebody explain to me how to get this done.

```
 
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name o.example.com;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
       proxy_redirect          off;
       proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       client_max_body_size    10m;
       client_body_buffer_size 128k;
       proxy_connect_timeout   90;
       proxy_send_timeout      90;
       proxy_read_timeout      90;
       proxy_buffers           32 4k;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

  }

}
```

This is what I have added to my conf but this does not seem to do what I expect it do. Am I missing something here. The thing is I store it as a separate .conf file and it gets added first before all other server information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I use

```
            location / {
                    proxy_read_timeout 2000;
                    proxy_next_upstream error;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                    break;

            }
```